# JLabels in GridLayout are Not Always Painted

Tags: java, swing, jlabel, paintcomponent, repaint

I am creating a basic Tic-Tac-Toe application in Java Swing, and for this purpose, I have started investigating drawing. However, I have encountered an issue when a subclass of `JPanel` contains more than one instance of a subclass of `JLabel`, which overrides the `paintComponent(Graphic)` method, in a `GridLayout` array format embedded in itself. The issue is that **only the first element in this array is painted**.

An example for the customized subclass of `JLabel`:

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;

import javax.swing.JLabel;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class DrawLabel extends JLabel {

    private boolean hasPaint;

    public DrawLabel() {
        super();
        this.hasPaint = false;
    }

    public void draw() {
        hasPaint = true;
        repaint();
    }

    public void clear() {
        hasPaint = false;
        repaint();
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        return new Dimension(200, 200);
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);

        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;

        if (hasPaint) {
            g2.drawOval(getX(), getY(), getWidth(), getHeight());
        } else {
            g2.clearRect(getX(), getY(), getWidth(), getHeight());
        }
    }
}
```

An example for the customized subclass of `JPanel`:

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.GridLayout;

import javax.swing.JPanel;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class DrawPanel extends JPanel {

    private Dimension size;
    private DrawLabel[][] fields;

    public DrawPanel(Dimension d) {
        super();
        this.size = d;
        this.fields = new DrawLabel[size.height][size.width];

        this.setLayout(new GridLayout(size.height, size.width));

        for (int i = 0; i < size.height; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < size.width; j++) {
                this.fields[i][j] = new DrawLabel();
                this.add(fields[i][j]);
            }
        }
    }

    public void draw(int row, int col) {
        fields[row][col].draw();
    }

    public void clear() {
        for (int i = 0; i < size.height; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < size.width; j++) {
                fields[i][j].clear();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

An example of an issue-provoking scenario:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Driver {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DrawPanel board = new DrawPanel(new Dimension(2, 1));

        JFrame canvas = new JFrame();
        canvas.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        canvas.add(board, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        canvas.pack();

        canvas.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        canvas.setVisible(true);

        board.draw(0, 0); // This gets painted.
        board.draw(0, 1); // This does not get painted!
    }

}
```

Curiously, if the `DrawPanel.draw(int, int)` is changed to set the text of the element rather than draw upon it, only the second element is updated, while the first is not, which is the exact opposite of the original problem.

I have tried to look up other issues and questions related to painting of subcomponents, but I have yet to find an issue like this one, where it seems that every instance beyond the first in the `GridLayout` are not drawable in the same way. What could be wrong?

Thank you for your time and effort!

Comment: MarkLabel missing repaint()

Comment: @mKorbel Painting is expected to occur at MarkLabel.drawMark(Mark), which also contains a call to repaint().

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Verifiable Example) or [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example).

Comment: *"..I will make sure to do this in the future!"*  Then I'll have to make sure I pay attention to your questions ..in the future.  Of course, it is possible to [edit this question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/27294527/edit) *right now.*

Comment: @AndrewThompson My apoligies. I have minimized the scope of the problem instance at display while maintaining the same separation. Is there anything else I can do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
g2.drawOval(getX(), getY(), getWidth(), getHeight());
```

Painting of a component is done relative to the component, not the panel the component is painted in. The getX/Y() methods return the location of the component relative to the parent component.

So if the size of each component is (200, 200) then the oval of the first component will be painted using

```
g2.drawOval(0, 0, 200, 200);
```

The second component will be painted at:

```
g2.drawOval(200, 0, 200, 200);
```

but since the component is only 200 pixels wide, the start x location of 200 is outside the bounds of the component so there is nothing to paint.

Instead just use:

```
g2.drawOval(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
```

Comment: It solves the issue to replace `getX()` and `getY()` with zeros! I did realize that these methods returned the child component origin relative to its parent component, however, I did not realize that painting had to be relative to the child itself, not the parent. Thank you!